# Graphviz: place a node under all other nodes

Tags: graphviz

```
digraph G {
    graph [label = "TGH5 SDK\n\n\n", labelloc = t, labeljust = center,
           fontname = Helvetica, fontsize = 18]
    labeljust = center;
    ranksep = .5;
    node [shape = "box", style = rounded, fontsize = 12];
    edge [fontsize = 9];
    subgraph cluster_0 {
        label = "External Services";
        style = "dashed";
        Language -> Geodata [style = "invis"];
        Geodata -> Advertisement [style = "invis"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label = "SDK";
        style = "dashed";
        Adapter -> Api;
    }
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        label = "Vendors";
        style = "dashed";
        Philips -> Opera [style = "invis"];
        Opera -> More [style = "invis"];
    }

    Language -> Api [constraint = false];
    Advertisement -> Api [constraint = false];
    Geodata -> Api [constraint = false];
    Philips -> Adapter [constraint = false];
    Opera -> Adapter [constraint = false];
    More -> Adapter [constraint = false];

    Game -> Api [rank = max, dir = both, constraint = false];
}
```

I want `Game` node to be placed below other three boxes, but cannot figure out how to do it. Sorry, I'm very new to Graphviz - actually that's the first time I'm trying to do something with it. So I don't really know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appended changes will give you the required output. The problem is that the invisible edges are required to push the Game node to below all the other nodes. In general, forcing layout to contain more than the structure you can describe with edge precedence is actually quite difficult.

```
Api -> Game [dir = both];
{ Advertisement; More } -> Game [style = invis];
```

Comment: Thanks, although this particular question has expired, I'm now looking forward to using Graphviz syntax with neo4j (a graph-based database), but I'm really struggling to find a good reference to the language (actually, apart of some examples, I've found nothing at all). Would you happen to recommend one?

Comment: Best reference is the guide [Drawing graphs with dot](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf). Most of the other documentation is reference material and more difficult to start with.